# Why does this `POST` request work and not work

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was demoing an app for a class I was teaching and ran into a bug. I was demo'ing `POST` requests in a Sinatra application. Here's my routes:

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/reloader"
first_names = []
get '/' do
  @first_names = first_names
  erb :index
end

post '/add_name' do
  first_names << params[:first_name]
  redirect "/"
end
```

In the `index.erb`:

```
<h1>All Names</h1>
<% @first_names.each do |name| %>
  <div><%= name %></div>
<% end %>
<h2>Enter New Name Here and Hit Enter</h2>
<form action="add_name" method="post">
  <input name='first_name'>
  <input type="submit" value="Add First Name"
</form>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-contrib"
```

Notice the unclosed `input` tag in the form. THIS actually works. Which is fine, HTML is buggy? But the part, that trips me up, is if I change the `action` of the form to `addd_name`(mispelled). It doesn't give me the error I expect. "Sinatra doesn't know this diddy...." It just does nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure it works with the missing end tag (clicking the button, not just pressing enter)? I think what is happening is that the missing `>` is causing the browser to parse the closing `</form>` as  two attributes to the input: `<`  (which isn’t valid) and `form` (it seems to ignore the `/` altogether). In HTML, `input` elements can have a `form` attribute, and so the result is the submit button is being associated with a non-existent form instead of the parent form, so clicking it has effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Your code has syntax errors; Both occurrences of `first_names` are undefined, however `@first_names` is only assigned in your `get` handler. As @matt says, you're missing the trailing `>`, however browsers might be able to do some fix-up and render the page correctly. Still, you should make your HTML be syntactically correct too.

Comment: I just put the relevant code that was part of the problem. I can extend my question, i understand, i was trying to be Minimal.

Comment: @matt thanks, that makes sense

Comment: but clicking it submits a request (with the missing `>`) when its the right action. thats the weird part. But doesn't throw an error when its the wrong action. just doesn't submit any request

Comment: What browser are you using? When I try with Chrome, Firefox or Safari it _doesn’t_ work by clicking the button when the `<` is missing (it does work if you press enter).

Comment: I'm using chrome, i think what was happening was i was hitting enter to submit the form. Which does work, but doesn't throw an error when i submit the form with enter with the wrong action.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the input tag and try to misspell action as `'/addd_name'` you'll get that ditty error :)

It that case, browser do not handle your "form" as a form. Check your network tab from developer console. You'll see that nothing happens when you click submit button.

Btw, if you've not declared  (e.g. in `configure do ... end` block) `first_names` array, you'll get another error - nilClass or sth like that.

Comment: `first_names` is just instantiated in the `app.rb` as an empty array.

Comment: not if the action is wrong, the problem is that it isn't giving me a problem.